# Windows Server 2012 IIS PHP Unable to set timezone through php.ini

Tags: php, windows, timezone

My windows server 2012 system timezone is set as UTC8 Kuala Lumpur/Singapore.

I found that PHP time differs from system time, it returns a UTC time. Then i try to set the timezone at php.ini where i set it as

date.timezone = "Asia/Singapore"

I restarted the server after changing the PHP ini and it still returns UTC time.
phpinfo() shown these values

```
date

date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2013.2
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    Europe/Dublin

Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   Europe/Dublin   Europe/Dublin
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: How does PHP return UTC time? Can you elaborate this? In php.ini you have set `Europe/Dublin`...

Comment: In php.ini i have already set date.timezone = "Asia/Singapore".
Somehow phpinfo still return Europe/Dublin and there is only one php.ini file in the server which is located at C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php.ini

Comment: The result from time() is current UTC time.

Answer (score 0):

check if there is `date.timezone` under `[WebPIChanges]` and change it to `Asia/Singapore`. I solved My issue by this way. Hope this will help you.